# How do I get a usabled List object for this code in C# using LINQ to XML?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-phone-7

Newbie to C# here....

I have the following code:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            var result = xdoc.Root.Elements("item")
                .Select(itemElem => itemElem.Elements().ToDictionary(e => e.Name.LocalName, e => e.Value))
                .ToList();
```

but when I try to use `result` as I would any `List` object, such as `result.Item`, it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong? Why is result not coming back as a normal List object that I can manipluate in my code? Do I need to make another List object from it?

I am just trying to get the first Dictionary item out of the List and use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you *expected*. Your code currently produces a `List<Dictionary<string,string>>`. So each entry in the list would be a dictionary.

You can access each dictionary as you usually would access list elements, i.e.

```
string firstResult = result[0]["key"];
```

The first part `[0]` is the indexer of the list the second part `["key"]` is the indexer of the dictionary - this would return the value for the key `"key"` of the first dictionary in your list.

This assumes the list has at least one entry though for which you would have to check.

Comment: Ok, but how do I access the first Dictionary within that List?

Comment: result[0] is the first dictionary in the resulting list. Note that if the list is empty, result[0] will throw an exception.  You can test to see if the list is empty testing result.Any() or result.Count() > 0.  You can use var x = result.FirstOrDefault() and test x for null.

Answer (score 0):

This is a `List<Dictionary<String, String>>`. Each element in the list is a Dictionary.

It would help to know what you wanted to do with it.

But some examples are:

```
//Get the First Dictionary Item, then Iterate through all the items in the first dictionary.
var firstItem = results.First();
foreach(var kvPair in firstItem)
{
    var key = kvPair.Key;
    var val = kvPair.Value;
}

//Loop through each Dictionary getting values from each.
foreach (var result in results)
{
    var wordValue = result["word"];
    var defValue = result["def"];
}

//Create a list of all the values for the Elements with the key "word".
var valuesForAllWords = 
  results
  .Select(r => r["word"])
```

Comment: I am just trying to get the first Dictionary item out of the List and use it.